# How do I execute a command prompt command from python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, cmd, python-requests

I have the following command and I execute it in command prompt:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mkv -i output.mkv -lavfi psnr=stats_file=psnrmkv.txt -f null -
```

this command computes PSNR between two files and saves the result in `pnsrmkv.txt`
but I have to enter this command for each video and I have more than 200 videos:(. now I am trying to execute it in python. each time I have to change the name of the input and output video and PSNR text file. is it any way to implement a command line in python? could you please help me with this issue? I am a beginner and if you have any code or link to explain sth like this, I will be really thankful. I am using windows and python 3.7. can `subprocess` help with this problem?

I used the following code, but it produces the error:

```
import subprocess as s
s.call(["command.exe", "ffmpeg.exe -i E:\mpeg_file\input.mkv -i E:\mpeg_file\2.mkv -lavfi psnr=stats_file=psnrmkv.txt -f null -"])
```

the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 2, in 
> s.call(["command.exe", "ffmpeg.exe -i E:\mpeg_file\input.mkv -i E:\mpeg_file\2.mkv -lavfi
> psnr=stats_file=psnrmkv.txt -f null -"])
>
> File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\subprocess.py", line 287,
> in call
> with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
>
> File
> "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
> line 105, in **init**
> super(SubprocessPopen, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\subprocess.py", line 729,
> in **init**
> restore_signals, start_new_session)
>
> File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1017,
> in _execute_child
> startupinfo)
>
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
> specified

Comment: You could use subprocess.call() to exceute shell commands.
This link might help
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-subprocess-to-run-external-programs-in-python-3

Comment: I was unable to find a duplicate for such a basic question; the duplicate I found discusses a slightly more complex scenario, but you should be able to find from it a good example of how to do what you are asking. Perhaps see also my top-voted answer, though that is primarily for Linux; nevertheless, much of it applies to Windows, too.

Comment: I wrote a small code that I add it above and it produces the error, do you know what is the problem?

Comment: Why do you want to run `command.exe`? Clearly no such binary exists in your `PATH`. Just `subprocess.call(['ffmpeg.exe', '-i', r'E:\mpeg_file\input.mkv', '-i', r'E:\mpeg_file\2.mkv', '-lavfi', 'psnr=stats_file=psnrmkv.txt', '-f', 'null', '-])`; notice also the `r'...'` prefix on strings with backslashes in them (though using a forward slash instead is easier and avoids this problem).

Comment: I added a couple of tangential duplicates.

Comment: I used your code and it produce output 0, but I need to save the file in specific location such as E:\mpeg_file\psnrmkv.txt, but when I used this code subprocess.call(['ffmpeg.exe', '-i', r'E:\mpeg_file\input.mkv', '-i', r'E:\mpeg_file\2.mkv', '-lavfi', 'psnr=stats_file=' r'E:\mpeg_file\psnrmkv2.txt', '-f', 'null', '-']) it could not produce the output and the output is 1. do you know why?